# Jquery save html with value in file

Tags: jquery

I have to save the contents of a div inside a text file, the div contains the input form that can be modified.
Can I save the html of the div with the field value changed?
ex:

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <input id="myInput" value="" />
</div>
```

after I edit the input on my html page, I insert "myChangedValue" inside the input field.
When I do $("myDiv").html() the content have the value field empty, and the structure of my txt file is:

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <input id="myInput" value="" />
</div>
```

I expected:

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <input id="myInput" value="myChangedValue" />
</div>
```

tnks

Comment: How are you going to get access to the text file? (You can use innerHTML on the div, btw)

Comment: Javascript does not support client I/O, how are you accomplishing the saving?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but really you need to spend a bit more time explaining what you intend. Do you want to save the value so that other people can see the value too after some time?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;
```

Get's the textual html content of the div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myDiv').html()
```

This will get you the HTML data inside `myDiv` as a string.  It's the jQuery version of @Raynos' answer.

As for saving the file, you'll need to pass this string to a server-side script to generate the file for download.

Comment: tnks,
I do that, but the modified values inside the div will not be saved inside the text file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of the input, you'd actually use:

```
document.getElementById("myInput").value;
```

Not sure how you'll be saving to TXT file without server side code.